# How to build sorm for scala 2.10.1

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, sorm

Any idea how to build [SORM](http://sorm-framework.org/) for scala 2.10.1 I am trying to generate a jar file that I can use in my eclipse project.

Here is my code

```
import sorm._
case class Coffee(name: String, supplier: Supplier, price: Double, sales: Int, total: Int)
case class Supplier(name: String, street: String, city: String, state: String, zip: String)

object Db extends Instance(
 entities = Set(Entity[Coffee](),Entity[Supplier])),url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db123")



object sormtest {

 import Db._
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
 val supplier1 = Supplier("Acme, Inc.", "99 Market Street", "Groundsville", "CA", "95199")
val supplier2 = Supplier("Superior Coffee", "1 Party Place", "Mendocino", "CA", "95460")
val supplier3 = Supplier("The High Ground", "100 Coffee Lane", "Meadows", "CA", "93966")


 Db.save(supplier2)  }}`
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/AbstractPoolBackedDataSource
    at sorm.core.Connector.<init>(Connector.scala:16)
    at sorm.Instance$Initialization.<init>(Instance.scala:209)
    at sorm.Instance.<init>(Instance.scala:29)
    at Db$.<init>(sormtest.scala:8)
    at Db$.<clinit>(sormtest.scala)
    at sormtest$.main(sormtest.scala:27)
    at sormtest.main(sormtest.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

I have already downloaded the jar file from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sorm-framework/sorm/0.3.8

EDIT: 
The Maven repository lists a number of jar files to be included. Once I added them that solved my problem.

Comment: The problem you're dealing with has nothing to do with neither SORM nor Scala. From the error message it's evident that you're missing other jars, which SORM depends on, on the classpath. They are listed on the link provided by Gourlaysama. I'd strongly suggest simply using Maven or SBT though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to build it yourself, SORM 0.3.8 is [available on Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sorm-framework/sorm/0.3.8), and supports Scala 2.10.x.

SBT:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.8"
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.sorm-framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>sorm</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.8</version>
</dependency>
```

If you really want the JAR, [you can download it from there too](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sorm-framework/sorm/0.3.8/sorm-0.3.8.jar).